# Why My internet stopped working after connect with NordLayer VPN Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, internet, vpn

I have faced an issue after connecting NordLayer VPN.
Once I connect with Nordlayer VPN, My Internet stopped working and only accessed VPN content only via CLI.

If I go to the browser and search for anything, it will not work, and seems like the internet connection is down. If I disconnect with VPN, everything is working fine in the browser.

When I connect with Nordlayer, VPN status looks like,

```
nordlayer status
Login: Logged in
VPN: Connected
Current network: Rakesh
Gateway: MY_GATEWAY_ID
Server address: VPN_IP_ADDRESS
Protocol: IKEv2/IPSec
```

How to access the internet once you connect with Nordlayer VPN?

Comment: What's the terminal output of `nordlayer status`? Does it show as being properly connected? Do you have more than one network connection active at a time? Have you checked to ensure the browsers are respecting the VPN connection?

Comment: @matigo Please check my updated question.

Comment: I would be asking the Nord VPN people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Contact with the NordLayer Support team they have given a link to resolved the issue for the Linux Operating system.

Just follow the link, [FIXED: NordLayer VPN Stopped Working after connecting VPN](https://help.nordlayer.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019768898-How-to-change-the-protocol-on-NordLayer-application-for-Linux-)

Just follow the steps given in the link, and choose the third option (OpenVPN TCP). It's work for me.

```
Select setting to change: 
1: VPN Protocol
2: Auto-connect
3: Always connect to
4: ThreatBlock
5: Smart remote access device name

Select [number]: 1

Available values for VPN Protocol
1: Automatic
2: IKEv2/IPSec
3: OpenVPN TCP
4: OpenVPN UDP
```

You have to choose all the options manually four times to resolve the issue.